# if condition inside for loop in java

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, arraylist

I am going to design a method which receives an arraylist that contains n of class a. In addition, it will receives two variables start and end . i want to test this condition for those classes between start and end variables. for example, if start = 5 and end = 12 . i want to check if the classes { 5, 6,7,8,9,10,11,12} achieve this condition or not

This is part of my code

```
    static void checkDonothing(ArrayList<tt> Result , int condations, int start, int end){

    for(int i = 0; i<Result.size(); i++){

       if (  Result.get(i).number >= start &&  Result.get(i).number <=end){
               //// do action 
                }       
            }
        }
```

I want to do the action if the condation is true for all these classes btween end and start.

Do you have any suggestion to do that ?

Comment: What condition would you be checking for? What kind of classes are going to be in the ArrayList? What is the `condations` parameter for?

Answer (score 0):

Reverse your condition and `return` if it passes. Otherwise do the action after the loop.

```
static void checkDonothing(ArrayList<tt> Result , int condations, int start, int end){

    for(int i = 0; i<Result.size(); i++){

        if (!(Result.get(i).number >= start &&  Result.get(i).number <=end)){
           // Note the ! (not) added in the condition to reverse it.
           return;
        }       
    }

    // If it arrives here, your condition has passed for all.
    // So, do the action.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 8 you can do something like this:

```
static void checkDonothing(ArrayList<tt> Result , int condations, int start, int end){
    boolean doAction = Result.stream().limit(end).skip(start)
            .allMatch(obj -> obj.equals(condations)/*write your custom condition here*/);
    if(doAction)
    {
        //Do action
    }
}
```